# Is there a reason Zuul Gateway doesn't work on App Engine?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, netflix-zuul

I have setup a zuul gateway which working when I run the application using spring-boot:run.

As soon as I run using appengine:run I get a `com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception`

Is there any reason why you can't use a zuul on App Engine Standard?

Comment: Do I need to move from App Engine standard to Flexible?

Comment: Hi, my comment is not related to this question but relevant more to GCP deployment. Since you're talking about Zuul I wanted to know if you're connecting it to Eureka Server in GAE? 'Cause my GAE microservice instances register themselves using a weird address. If so can you please detail me how you manage to make it work?